# Majority Element link - https://leetcode.com/problems/majority-element/

Tags: arrays

//This code is on to find majority element in the arrays so when I give the user input [3,3,4] then it returns 4 instead of 3 idk why Below I have given the link of the leetcode where the actual question is//
https://leetcode.com/problems/majority-element

```
class Solution {
            //1st func
            public static int countInRange(int nums[],int num,int si,int ei){
                int count = 0;
                for(int i = si;i<=ei;i++){
                    if(si==ei){
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                return count;
             }  
            //2nd func
            private static int majorityElementRec(int nums[],int si,int ei){
                //Base case 
                if(si==ei){
                    return nums[si];
                }
                //kaam - recurse on left and rigth halves of this slice 
                //find middle element
                int mid = si+(ei-si)/2;
                //find left half and right half
                int left = majorityElementRec(nums,si,mid);
                int right = majorityElementRec(nums,mid+1,ei);
                
                //if the two halves accept the majority element return them as majority
                if(left==right){
                    return left;
                }
                //otherwise count each element
                int leftCount = countInRange(nums,left,si,ei);
                int rightCount = countInRange(nums,right,si,ei);
                //Compare both leftCount and rightCount and return left as winner
                return leftCount>rightCount? left:right;
                
            }
            //3rd func
                public int majorityElement(int[] nums) {
                    return majorityElementRec(nums,0,nums.length-1);
                }
        }
```

Comment: what language is that?

Comment: Java programming